Hydration Error with Next.js and React after upgrading
I have a project that I didn't work on for quite some time, and meanwhile Next.js moved forward and had a lot of new versions, so before continuing with my project, I upgraded Next.js from version 10 to 14, and React from version 16 to 18 and fix through stuff, before I go on with really developing it.
Now my application seems to run all right, there are some small bugs that I have noticed so far, but nothing too bad, but I will probably figure out some more later.
Currently I have only one issue, and is this UI hydration mismatch, because of server and client-side rendering mismatch. The thing is i don't have the shown code in my codebase. I do not have  and neither  elements. Also there is no real stack trace and I don't know what component this is coming from.
(https://i.sstatic.net/bdWW4cUr.png)
(https://i.sstatic.net/4a6UlqcL.png)
I tried deleting node_modules, and .next folder, but hasn't worked so far. I don't know which component this is coming from and how I can find out.
